# Default color doesn't match palette for components inside AppBar

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm starting to use **material-ui-next (branch next aka v1)** for a ReactJS web app. 
I've found some difficulties in setting what should have been the default and expected color for a Typography component that is placed inside an AppBar.

I've defined this [material palette](https://material.io/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=3F51B5&secondary.color=03A9F4) and as you can see by choosing indigo as primary color, automatically the text primary color is set to white (#ffffff). This is also confirmed looking at the indigo palette from the official [material documentation](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette).

However the default color turns out to be black. If I set the `color` property to `default` it remains black, the only way to make it working is to set the it to `inherit`.

Why should I do it? Am I missing something?

I've [also seen that](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#the-other-variables) in a theme one may customise also `text` property.
Is this the right track? And, if yes, how can I use text.primary for instance, since [docs states](https://material-ui-next.com/api/typography/) that Typography can only accept as values `default|accent|error|primary|secondary|inherit`?

The same problem happens with IconButton as well.

Below you can find my code. In the constructor I set the palette custom values, then in `render()` I pass the theme to `MuiThemeProvider`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { indigo, lightBlue, red } from 'material-ui/colors';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography/Typography';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import DeleteIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Delete';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const options = {
      palette: {
        primary: indigo,
        secondary: lightBlue,
        error: red,
      },
    };

    this.theme = createMuiTheme(options);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={this.theme}>
        <AppBar>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography color="inherit">
              My App
            </Typography>
            <IconButton color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
              <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './material/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit contort but, however, this is how it is supposed to be: a theme has  to be as complete as possible to cover all your needs. Defining only primary and secondary colors will not suffice, you need to exploit all the possibilities offered by the configuration JSON object, otherwise it is going to use defaults.

Going into a bit of detail, assume you want an Input component (works in the same way for Typography problem I had, but this example is more complete) to have white text and white underline you can create a theme that wraps that Input component by passing this options object:

```
const options = {
  palette: {
    text: {
      primary: grey[50],
    },
    input: {
      bottomLine: grey[50],
      inputText: grey[50],
    }
  },
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme(options)}>
    <Input
      label="File name"
      placeholder="Untitled-1"
      required
    />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Or alternatively, define a styles object exploiting each component style structure (available from API section of official documentation), and use it as withStyles() component.

```
  const styles = {
    root: {
      color: 'white',
    },
    underline: {
      '&:before': {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      },
      '&:hover:not($disabled):before': {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: 2,
      },
    },
  };
```

And set the style like this:

```
  <Input
    classes={{
      root: classes.root,
      underline: classes.underline,
    }}
    label="File name"
    placeholder="Untitled-1"
    required
  />
```

Don't forget to export as withStyles() component.

```
 export default withStyles(styles)(FileName);
```

Maybe there's a quickest way, but this worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';


const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary1Color: "#000000", //primary
    accent1Color: "#741b1d", //seconday
  }
});
```

and

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
```

also

```
palette: {
    primary1Color: Colors.cyan500,
    primary2Color: Colors.cyan700,
    primary3Color: Colors.lightBlack,
    accent1Color: Colors.pinkA200,
    accent2Color: Colors.grey100,
    accent3Color: Colors.grey500,
    textColor: Colors.deepPurpleA700,
    alternateTextColor: Colors.white,
    canvasColor: Colors.white,
    borderColor: Colors.grey300,
    disabledColor: ColorManipulator.fade(Colors.darkBlack, 0.3),
    pickerHeaderColor: Colors.cyan500,
  }
```

Comment: This response is valid only for v0.X, which is not what I'm asking for.